# rendering sub view in express gives 404 error

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, pug

I am using express and jade to render a web page. I want to render the page in this format 'http://127.0.0.1:5000/services/landfreight' but I keep getting 404.

```
router.get('/service/landfreight', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('service/landfreight', { title: 'landfreight' });
});
```

my views folder  is arranged in this format.

- views

  - services.jade
  - services

    - landfreight.jade

please how can I render it

Comment: the problem is you do services in the url with  s but in the route without it you need to make both the same

Answer (score 2):

there is an `s` in `services` in the URL `http://127.0.0.1:5000/services/landfreight`
while there isn't in your code

try `http://127.0.0.1:5000/service/landfreight`